# How can I add two strings?

Tags: c, string, pointers

of size 5, that I want to add, according to some conditions that I will impose. Both strings are in the format 00:00. The first string (s1) represents a certain time of departure of a plane, the second one, is how delayed that departure will be...
This is supposed to be done on a 24h clock.

Let's say, for example
s1=10:45 
s1=01:50

so first I have to add the 5 and the 0, see if there's a carry out and if the result is under 9, then add the 4 and the 5, see if the result is under 6. If it isn't I subtract 6 to the addition and add the carry out (1) to the 0 and the 1, then I'll add 1 to 0.

5+0=5

4+5=9   9-6=3  carry out:1

0+1+1=2

0+1=1

12:35

What I would like to obtain is s1=12:35

I don't really get how pointers work... I've tried to understand them, but it was in vain...

Can you help me?

I have some ideas that I will post here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char*add_hours(char s1[], char s2[])
   int i;
   for(i=4; i>3; i--){
    if(s1[i]+s2[i]>9){
      strcpy(s1[i], ((s1[i]+s2[i])-10); 
      strcpy(s1[i-1], (s1[i-1]+1));
    } 
...
}
```

the code goes on for a little while, but it repeats itself a few times. So I didn't think I needed to copy it all here. The problem is, he keeps telling me showing this warning:

`"warning: passing argument 1 of 'strcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast
/usr/include/string.h:128: note: expected 'const char * _restrict_' but argument if of type 'int'`

And the same thing for the second argument, for every strcpy there is... I understand the error (I think) but I don't know how to correct it...

Comment: You need to use numeric data types to perform the addition you are intending. Try with int.

Comment: Please do not forget there is no such thing as a string it is a char array

Answer (score 4):

I may be wrong, but I think you don't want to add like that.

What happens if you have a depature at 00:30 and an arrival at 04:00, but daylight savings happens inbetween?

Populate a time_t structure.  Convert that to a time_t.  Add your delay, in seconds.  Convert that back to a time_t.  Print that out using strftme().  Let the time code in the C library deal with all these issues.

Comment: @David I'd say that its a good answer for learning about C but a bad answer for learning how to program.

Comment: @Null: I was thinking something similar... there are multiple lessons in this homework exercise, some of them negative.

Comment: +1: Even if he's not going to use the standard library to do the work, he should almost certainly follow the same model -- convert the strings to times in seconds (or whatever unit is most convenient) since some epoch, do the math on those, then convert the result back to something readable.

Comment: dayligh saving time is such a complicated thing to be taken into account... the OP is talking about departure and delays, so it is about the specific country where the airplane is currently awaiting for departure. each contry has its own idea about it... I suppose it can be disregarded!

Comment: @Shin: if I was waiting for a flight and the delay time was displayed and it was *wrong by an hour*, I'd be pretty annoyed!  especially if I were say missing a connecting flight and making alternative arrangedments and then I arrive at the wrong time.  I don't think that's something you can disregard at all.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should remove the for loop.  It just makes 2 iterations and it is confusing.
Then, the first line of your function should be

```
 char * sum = new char[5];
```

since you probably want to return a new string. It will also make things clearer.

Try to decompose things in order to simplify your problem. Start writing:

```
int minutes(char * s);
int hours(char * s);
```

That respectively return the number of minutes and hours expressed in a string.

Answer (score 0):

`strcpy` expects strings (array of char/char pointer) as its parameters. What you are giving it are single characters. If you want to modify single characters that way, there is no need to use `strcpy`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char*add_hours(char s1[], char s2[])
   int i;
   for(i=4; i>3; i--){
    if(s1[i]+s2[i]>9){
      s1[i] = (s1[i]+s2[i])-10; 
      s1[i-1] = s1[i-1]+1;
    } 
...
}
```

There are other logical problems with the code, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const int MINS_IN_HR = 60;

int StrToMins(char* str)
{
    int res = 0;
    char temp[3];   
    temp[2] = '\0';
    memcpy(temp, str, 2);   
    res += atoi(temp)*MINS_IN_HR;
    memcpy(temp, str+3, 2); 
    res += atoi(temp);
    return res;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char* s1="10:45", *s2="01:50";
    int totalMins = StrToMins(s1) + StrToMins(s2);

    printf("%d:%d", totalMins / MINS_IN_HR, totalMins % MINS_IN_HR);
    return 0;
}
```